# Searching for a dictionary value in an array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to search an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has different keys and values like Name, Age and Joindate.

I do the searching based on a tutorial by the following code:

```
- (void) searchTableView {

NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
{
    NSArray *array = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
}

for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length != 0)
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}

[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil; }
```

The searching goes well and the data is displayed correctly.

The Problem is when I choose one of the results it will point to a wrong location.

Here is how the selected row is directed to the detail view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *selectedName = nil;

    if(searching) 

    selectedName = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    else {

        selectedApp = [[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];      
    }

 [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithAppData:[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] nibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

controller.selectedName = selectedName;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];  
    [DetailViewController release];
```

}

I need a way to point to the correct location.

If I could find the index of the Name I'm looking for in the main array it would be great.

It would be much appreciated if u could help me with this.

Comment: Does the array 'listOfItems' have the correct indexes? It's not clear from your code where that array comes from.

Answer (score -1):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and add some fields for storing where exactly did you find whatever is displayed in the cell (like in which dictionary and at what position in the array). Then you'll be able to easily get that when the cell is clicked.